# wordpress localization

Tags: wordpress

I am using a `.mo` file in my language directory of `wp-content`. But It doesn't trnslate some words and all the numerical contents of the site. How can I add these to the `.mo` file? Or is there any other way to translate those contents?

Comment: Can you show an example of how you gettext the string that doesn't get translated? And how you add it to .po file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Poedit http://www.poedit.net/ (open source) for that. You edit the .po file and then save it as a .mo file.

Some explanation you can find here: 
[Adding languages to Wordpress](http://themekraft.com/add-your-own-language-files-to-wordpress-plugins-with-poedit/)